# FullCalendar Add checkbox inside event

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar

I need to add a checkbox inside the event card.

The checkbox will be used to select the event instead of opening it.

If the user clicks on the event itself (not on the checkbox) the event will open for edition.

But if the user clicks on the checkbox, the event will be selected instead of opening it.

I am using the eventClick to open the event and it's working fine.
I have added the checkbox on the event HTML.

However, when I click on the checkbox, the eventClick is trigged and the (change) event on checkbox is not trigged.

I am using Angular.

See code below:

Event click:

```
eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
```

Event HTML

```
'<div>' +
   '<input class="form-check-input" (change)="ShiftSelect($event)" type="checkbox" />' +
'</div>'
```

Event not triggered:

```
ShiftSelect(values:any){
    this.isChangeOption = true;
}
```

Event triggered:

```
handleEventClick(info: EventClickArg) {}
```

Event:
[image]

I have tried deleting the eventClick to see if the checkbox event will be triggered but it was not.

Comment: I think because fullCalendar handles event clicks on the whole event, it somehow suppresses any events from within the calendar content from being triggered. So far I haven't found a way round this myself. Maybe raise a ticket on the fullcalendar github page and see if the team can suggest anything. Post your answer on this page if you get a solution!